# REST API (Angular 15 + .Net Core 6) get 10mb of data takes more than 1min

Tags: json, .net, angular, rest, get

I need to transfer a big amount of data between my API (.net core 6) and my client (Angular 15), but it takes too much time, more than 1 minute for 11mb:

[image: Angular request]

This is my service on client side:

```
getMinuteByMinute(filters: IMbMTargetFiltersModel) : Observable<IMinuteByMinuteModel>{
    return this.http.post<IMinuteByMinuteModel>(`${this.apiURLXmlValid}/minute-by-minute`, filters); }
```

This is my subscriber:

```
this.xmlValidationService.getMinuteByMinute(filters)
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.endSubscribe$))
  .subscribe({
    next: (item) => {
      console.log(item);
    },
    error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {          
      this.messageServices.add({
        severity: 'error',
        summary: 'Erro',
        detail: 'Error loading minute by minute data'
      })
    }
});}
```

But when I use the Postman as client it is much more faster, just 1 second:

[image: Postman request]

What can I do to improve the performance of this request?

Thanks

Comment: If the object is complex, logging will Cost a little bit, but not a minute obviously. Maybe you have some browser debug setting enabled?